# Get file from any library in the web tree

Tags: spweb, spfile, spsite

Is it possible to use some built in SharePoint API to open a file no matter which web and library it's in?

Example:

Given the file: /subsiteA/PublishingImages/myimage.jpg
I want to open it and get the list item, but using this fails:

```
var url = "/subsiteA/PublishingImages/myimage.jpg";
var file = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.GetFile(url);
SPListItem item = file.GetListItem(); //Fails here with item not in library error
```

Naturally it will not work as the file is not located in the root web, but is there a generic way to locate the file no matter which web and library it's in and retrieve the SPListItem object related to the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very similar to above, [the SPSite object does actually remember the URL it was opened with](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/11/14/how-to-get-an-spweb-object-from-a-url/) - so you don't have to give a Web name. You should be able to use something like:

```
string url= "Full URL to File";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url)){
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
  { 
    SPFile file = web.GetFile(url); 
    SPListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields; 
  }      
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Though it seems like sort of a hack or maybe more like a "hidden feature".

Comment: Yeah, it isn't obvious that that should work. It's definitely not a hack - it's how parts of SharePoint work internally - but it could be better documented.

Comment: Just did a quick test and it works fine with "_layouts" urls too :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get file in such a way. I also really wanted to know if possible.

Other way, you have to code like:

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("yoursiteurl")){

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("subsiteA"))
 {
    SPFile file = web.GetFile("/subsiteA/PublishingImages/myimage.jpg");
    SPListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;
 }
```

}

Comment: This is close to the code I'm currently using, but my problem is that the image can come from any web. In my case I can split the string on "PublishingImages", but I was hoping to find some code that would allow me to make the code work for any library. Another alternative would be to split the string on "/" and attempt to open webs recursively down, but that is very expensive.